# "Not Authorized" error on GraphQL query call - AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

This is my Graphql schema:

```
type Ticket @model
  @auth(rules: [
    {allow: public, provider: apiKey},
    {allow: groups, groups: ["Admins","Moderators"], operations: [create, update, delete, read]},
    {allow: owner, ownerField: "authorizations", operations: [create, update, read]}
  ]){
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  createdBy: String!
  authorizations: [String]!
  emailCreatedBy: String!
  title: String!
  description: String!
}
```

With Amplify CLI I've set the GraphQL resource with "Amazon Cognito User Pool" as default authorization mode and API Key as second mode.

When I perform a POST request following this guide:
https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/graphql-from-lambda/q/platform/js/#query

I receive this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listTickets": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "listTickets"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "Unauthorized",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Not Authorized to access listTickets on type ModelTicketConnection"
    }
  ]
}
```

I perform a POST request to the AWS AppSync Endpoint with this body:

```
{
    "query": "query ListTickets{listTickets{items{id}}}",
    "authMode": "API_KEY"
}
```

and the "x-api-key" header with my api key value.

With a Cognito authenticated user instead works properly.

I receive the same error if I try with the Queries tool in the AWS AppSyncConsole in the browser.

I tried also with the "@aws_api_key" directive.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you grant AWS Cognito Groups enough permissions to access your DynamoDb resources?